# Standard Deviation in Normal Distribution (with only mean and unknown division)

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

My question comes when I revise the topic.
If the mean and simple information is given, how can I find the standard deviation?
i.e. For normally distributed data, let's say mean = 65, and only 5 % or the samples are >=90. How can I find the standard deviation within so lack of information. Is it possible? Thanks to anyone who can suggest and share your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

- $\Phi^{-1}(0.95)\approx 1.644854$ for a standard normal distribution
- so $5\%$ of a normal distribution is more than about $1.644854$ standard deviations above the mean
- and you know the mean

Comment: Thank you. May I know what is the first line: 1.644854 stands for please.

Comment: @ChristiePPP If you use the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal distribution (mean $0$ and variance $1$) then $\mathbb P(X \le  1.644854)=0.95$.  Here $\Phi^{-1}(0.95)\approx 1.644854$ uses the inverse of that function.  You can look this up in statistical tables

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I get the idea. 1.644854 σ=90- μ=90-65=25 ? Is it the case? Thank you very much !

Comment: @ChristiePPP you still need to do a division

Comment: Thanks and I got my answer 15.1989 (4 dec)! Really thanks for your sharing.